# Check duplicate index value in listveiw

Tags: c#, listview, c#-3.0

I have a listview in C# with `columns(ProdcutId,ProductName,UnitPirce,Quantity)`. I am inserting data in it from text boxes`(txtproid,txtproname,txtunitprice,txtquantity)`. All these txtboxes are inserted once on a button click. What I want here is when i click the button,it should check the ProductId column in listview. If it contain the value coming from 'txtproid', It should not add all txtboxes in listview instead should show a messaage "This Product is Already Included". It should not check the whole item in listv.

I have tried many things but invain like:

```
int c = 0;
if (listView1.Items.Count != 0)
{
     foreach (ListViewItem lv in listView1.Items)
    {
        c = 0;
        if (lv.SubItems[0].Text == cmbpid.SelectedItem.ToString())
        {
            Validations.ErrorMessage("Item already exists in the Cart");
            c = 1;
        }
    }
}
else if (c == 0)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(cmbpid.Text);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(cmbpname.Text);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(txtunitprice.Text);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(txtproquantity.Text);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(txtunittotal.Text);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(txtbatch.Text);
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    //clear fields
    quvar = 0;
    totalvar = 0;
    txtproquantity.Clear();
    txtunitprice.Clear();
    txtunittotal.Clear();
    GetListviewTotal();
    txtbatch.Clear();
    cmbpid.SelectedIndex = -1;
    cmbpname.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is divided two small functions.

First, check duplicate product id.(Let's say `CheckSameProductId()`)
Second, insert data to ListView.(Let's say `InsertProductData()`)

So, below form can be.

```
if (CheckDuplicateId())
{
    //show error text
}
else
{
    //insert text boxes's data to List View
    InsertProductData();
}
```

And then, each function can write, for example.

```
 //check whether it's already inserted
  bool CheckDuplicateId()
  {
      foreach (ListViewItem lv in listView1.Items)
      {
          if (lv.SubItems[0].Text == cmbpid.SelectedItem.ToString())
          {
              //there is a duplicate data
              return true;
          }
      }

      //there is no duplicate data
      return false;
  }

  //insert data using text boxes to listview ctrl
  void InsertProductData()
  {
      foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
      {
          if (x is TextBox)
          {
              //I'm not sure your control z-order
              lvi.SubItems.Add(((TextBox)x).Text);
          }
      }
  }
```

I've not compiled above code, so you have to check that.